# Firebase Test Lab. GameLoop - marking test completed doesn't work for IOS

Tags: firebase, firebase-test-lab

**Desired behavior**
When the finish loop test in the Firebase TestLab matrix should be marked as completed.

**Current behavior**
The test is not marked as completed. And fails due to timeout.

**Example Matrix**
matrix-301t6tmiencqn

**Platform**
IOS 12.0, 12.3. Unity 2019.1.14f1.

I am working on the implementation of the IOS game loop for Unity https://firebase.google.com/docs/test-lab/game-loop. I was able to implement all steps.
But when I am trying to mark the test completed it gets stuck on the "Game Loop Complete" screen and nothing happens.

I am using the method described in docs https://firebase.google.com/docs/test-lab/game-loop#end-early
 - to open the "firebase-game-loop-complete://" URL.

Here is Objective-C snippet of the method I call from my IOS wrapper:

```
// Your Game Loop test terminates the current loop and executes the next loop. When there are no more loops to run, the test ends.
-(void) finishLoop
{
    NSLog(@"[NativeIOSTestLab] FinishLoop called");
    UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    NSLog(@"[NativeIOSTestLab] Calling openURL method");
    [app openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"firebase-game-loop-complete://"] options:@{} completionHandler:^(BOOL success) {}];
}
```

I have also tried to close the app with the exit(0) method, but it still doesn't get marked as completed.[This is the result of the finish loop call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g4wDD.png) - it looks like it gets to complete the screen. But the test gets marked as failed after reaching the timeout.

Are there any known solutions, thank you!

Comment: If you have a bug report, please I suggest filing that with Firebase support.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: You need to post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: You have a question that is very specific for your use case and test. I would suggest to reach out to the Firebase Test Lab team [via the Firebase Community Slack](https://firebase-community.slack.com) to get help. Post in the #test-lab channel.

Comment: I have added code snipped, Desired, and Current behavior comment. Let me know if I need to add more details.

Comment: Thank you! The issue actually was that the default timeout wasn't enough to finish the test. After increasing the timeout, the test completed successfully. There are invite page to get into slack workspace https://firebase.community/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you! 
The issue actually was that the default timeout wasn't enough to finish the test, even if the video shows that tests have completed, there are expected offset for device pre-setup and post-run. 
After increasing the timeout, the test completed successfully.
The question has been answered in the slack community. 
Here is the page to get into slack workspace 
https://firebase.community/